# Selecting from an array with whitespace

Tags: arrays, bash, select, whitespace

With the code

```
array=('Hi There' 'How are you')

select x in ${array[@]}
do
echo $x
done
```

I get the result

```
 1. Hi
 2. There
 3. How
 4. are
 5. you
```

I need the output to be:

```
 1. Hi There
 2. How are you
```

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes.

```
array=('Hi There' 'How are you')
select x in "${array[@]}"
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

Double quotes on variables expansion are almost always advisable. [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/388654)

Comment: Even more strongly, there is *never* a reason to leave `${array[@]}` unquoted; without quotes, it is identical to `${array[*]}`. It's reason for *being* is to be quoted.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate you taking the time.